# API that makes heapdump snapshot does not work

Tags: node.js, heap-dump

First of all, I'm a node js beginner.

I installed the heapdump module to track the heap memory leak in the vm. And I created an api that makes snapshots.
On the first day of the deployment, a snapshot was successfully taken (approximately 5 seconds), but since three days after deployment, the same api was called, but it stopped and did not respond.

How do I solve this problem?
I reinstalled the module and tried to redistribute the code, but it didn't work.

node js version: v14.18.1 /
heapdump version: "^0.3.15"

Comment: Does the API work properly? Are there any errors or logs generated by that API?

Comment: There is a log that the REQUEST has come, but after that, no log remains and no response.

Comment: Have you handled failure scenarios in the code? If something goes wrong, the code should atleast log the incident.

Comment: there is a 'try-catch'. Is it 'failure scenario' you told?